# Does SOAP service OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ support DirectFlightsOnly="true" flag?

Tags: sabre

Calling SOAP service OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ works Ok but it seems that ignores the DirectFlightsOnly flag (DirectFlightsOnly="true").

Sabre service answer flights with more than one flight segment.
Here is the request:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:eb="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <eb:MessageHeader SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" eb:version="1.0">
        <eb:From>
            <eb:PartyId>Client</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:From>
        <eb:To>
            <eb:PartyId>SWS</eb:PartyId>
        </eb:To>
        <eb:CPAId>IPCC</eb:CPAId>
        <eb:ConversationId>8989</eb:ConversationId>
        <eb:Service>Session</eb:Service>
        <eb:Action>BargainFinderMaxRQ</eb:Action>
        <eb:MessageData>
            <eb:MessageId>1</eb:MessageId>
            <eb:Timestamp>2017-07-06T13:35:44-05:00</eb:Timestamp>
        </eb:MessageData>
    </eb:MessageHeader>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/utility">
        <wsse:BinarySecurityToken>My Session Id</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" DirectFlightsOnly="true" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.0.0" Target="Test" Version="3.0.0">
        <POS>
            <Source PseudoCityCode="PCC">
                <RequestorID ID="1" Type="1">
                    <CompanyName Code="TN"/>
                </RequestorID>
            </Source>
        </POS>
        <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1">
            <DepartureDateTime>2017-09-09T11:00:00</DepartureDateTime>
            <OriginLocation LocationCode="MVD"/>
            <DestinationLocation LocationCode="EZE"/>
            <TPA_Extensions>
                <SegmentType Code="O"/>
            </TPA_Extensions>
        </OriginDestinationInformation>
        <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true">
            <CabinPref Cabin="Y" PreferLevel="Preferred"/>
            <TPA_Extensions>
                <TripType Value="Return"/>
                <LongConnectTime Enable="true" Max="1200" Min="780"/>
                <ExcludeCallDirectCarriers Enabled="true"/>
            </TPA_Extensions>
        </TravelPreferences>
        <TravelerInfoSummary>
            <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
            <AirTravelerAvail>
                <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1"/>
            </AirTravelerAvail>
        </TravelerInfoSummary>
        <TPA_Extensions>
            <IntelliSellTransaction>
                <RequestType Name="50ITINS"/>
            </IntelliSellTransaction>
        </TPA_Extensions>
    </OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

This is part of the answer (as you can see there are two [FlightSegmen]> nodes):

```
                    <AirItinerary DirectionInd="Return">
                    <OriginDestinationOptions>
                        <OriginDestinationOption ElapsedTime="1364">
                            <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-09-09T09:15:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-09-09T06:16:00" ElapsedTime="299" FlightNumber="904" ResBookDesigCode="L" StopQuantity="0">
                                <DepartureAirport LocationCode="MVD"/>
                                <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="LIM"/>
                                <OperatingAirline Code="AV" CompanyShortName="/TRANS AMERICAN AIRLINES" FlightNumber="904"/>
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="319"/>
                                <MarketingAirline Code="AV"/>
                                <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                                <DepartureTimeZone GMTOffset="-3"/>
                                <ArrivalTimeZone GMTOffset="-5"/>
                                <TPA_Extensions>
                                    <eTicket Ind="true"/>
                                </TPA_Extensions>
                            </FlightSegment>
                            <FlightSegment ArrivalDateTime="2017-09-10T05:00:00" DepartureDateTime="2017-09-09T22:50:00" ElapsedTime="250" FlightNumber="1365" ResBookDesigCode="Y" StopQuantity="0">
                                <DepartureAirport LocationCode="LIM"/>
                                <ArrivalAirport LocationCode="EZE" TerminalID="A"/>
                                <OperatingAirline Code="AR" FlightNumber="1365"/>
                                <Equipment AirEquipType="738"/>
                                <MarketingAirline Code="AR"/>
                                <MarriageGrp>O</MarriageGrp>
                                <DepartureTimeZone GMTOffset="-5"/>
                                <ArrivalTimeZone GMTOffset="-3"/>
                                <TPA_Extensions>
                                    <eTicket Ind="true"/>
                                </TPA_Extensions>
                            </FlightSegment>
                        </OriginDestinationOption>
                    </OriginDestinationOptions>
                </AirItinerary>
```

Comment: do you have own created sabre flight api code

Answer (score 1):

If that element doesn't work, go for maxnumstops or numberofconnections. Set it in 0, that will do the job.

Comment: None of these option exist. I just fixed with: <TravelPreferences ValidInterlineTicket="true" MaxStopsQuantity="0">